# Can't access static files while deploying Django app with apache2 load balancer

Tags: django, apache, apache2, load-balancing, static-files

I'm trying to deploy a couple of apps developed in Django. Initially, I deployed the apps on a single server and everything worked smoothly. Now I'm trying to implement the site using load balancing with Apache2 load balance module. The problem is that when redirecting the traffic to the different sites, I get correctly to each site, but the static files are not accessible. I tried any trick I found through Google without success. I'm using Apache 2.4 and Gunicorn 20.1.0 (as the backend). The apps were developed with Django 3.1.1.
Those are my apache config for the load balancer and for the servers:

### Load Balancer (apache2.4)

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName sites.example.com

    ProxyRequests off
    <Proxy balancer://cluster>
        BalancerMember https://site1.example.com route=192-168-10-10
        BalancerMember https://site2.example.com route=192-168-10-15
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from none
        Allow from all
        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    </Proxy>

    <Location /balancer-manager>
        SetHandler balancer-manager
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Location>


    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
    ProxyPass / balancer://cluster
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://cluster

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off


    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sites.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sites.example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/lb_clients_certs.pem

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### Server1

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sites.example.com
    ServerAlias site1.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass /static/ !
    Alias /static/ /var/www/myapp/static/
    #ProxyPass /static/   https://site1.example.com/static/
    #ProxyPassReverse /static/   https://site1.example.com/static/

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Directory /var/wwww/myapp/static/>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

     ProxyPass / http://192.168.10.10:8000/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.10.10:8000/

     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/fullchain1.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/privkey1.pem
     Include /etc/apache2/certs/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

### Server2

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sites.example.com
    ServerAlias site2.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass /static/ !
    Alias /static/ /var/www/myapp/static/
    #ProxyPass /static/   https://site2.example.com/static/
    #ProxyPassReverse /static/   https://site2.example.com/static/

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Directory /var/wwww/myapp/static/>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

     ProxyPass / http://192.168.10.15:8000/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.10.15:8000/

     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/fullchain1.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/privkey1.pem
     Include /etc/apache2/certs/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Important to note that when I access 'https://site1.example.com' and 'https://site2.example.com' I can see the sites correctly, but when accessing 'https://sites.example.com' I can see that each time the loader send to any of the two sites, but the static files are not loaded.

What is going wrong with my configuration?